# SOAP Service creation throws 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, soap-client

```
URL url = null;
try {
url = new URL("http://example:1211/MACSSWS/MCSKORDR.asmx?WSDL");
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
   throw new ServiceException(ex.getMessage());
}
MCSKORDR_Service mcskordr_Service = new MCSKORDR_Service(url);
```

This gives 401 unauthorized error at last line because the wsdl is authenticated with basic authentication. How to solve this problem?

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://example:1211/MACSSWS/MCSKORDR.asmx?WSDL. It failed with: 
    Server returned HTTP response code: 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this storing wsdl at client side.